# Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

Tags: java

```
public class Adder
{
public static void main(String arr[])
    {
    //System.in represents Standard Input Device (Keyboard)
    //Explain this next line, please:
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("Enter First No.");    
    int a = in.nextInt();    
    System.out.println("Enter Second No.");    
    int b = in.nextInt();    
    int c = a+b;    
    System.out.println("Sum is: "+c);    
    }    
}
```

I just started learning JAVA and i came across this code.Can someone explain me what does the *marked line* signify ?

Comment: You seem to lack basic knowledge of Java, it would be wise to follow a tutorial on classes for example

Comment: It creates a new `Scanner` object that listens to the standard input device. Which part is unclear?

Comment: Read the `Scanner` documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  The description at the top should help you understand it, even if you don't understand the entire page.

Comment: Just Read [#Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: @TAsk That documentation is _years_ out of date, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
```

The System.in in the above code tells the compiler to get the data typed in the Keyboard, Which is a input device

Thanks,

For more basic things in java Please checkout:
[Tutorialspoint.com](http://tutorialspoint.com/Java)