# Where is the keyboard specified the System.in method?

Tags: java

I can't conceptually understand in the below code (that retrieves characters from keyboards and prints to the command line)  where I specified that input must come from the keyboard?

```
public class Adder
{
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {

        //Explain this next line, please:
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("Enter First No.");    
        int a = in.nextInt();    
        System.out.println("Enter Second No.");    
        int b = in.nextInt();    
        int c = a+b;    
        System.out.println("Sum is: "+c);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: This question didn't go well the first time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144859/scanner-in-new-scannersystem-in

Comment: @Salman : I would say try to understand these three key words in the program Scanner, System.in and nextInt. You are all set

Comment: i think system.in open input stream from a device ? but why is that a keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) isn't a method, it's a field that's tied to your keyboard by default.

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

You can call the [`System.setIn(InputStream in)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) method to change it to a different input stream.

Reference: [I/O from the Command Line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Lets break it down

**Scanner:** The Scanner class is a class in java.util, which allows the user to read values of various types

**System.in:** An InputStream which is typically connected to keyboard input of console programs

```
                         Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in)
```

above line will invoke Constructor of Scanner class with argument System.in, and will return a reference to newly constructed object.

S is connected to a Input Stream that is connected to Keyboard, so now at run-time you can take user input to do required operation.

further study:
[Scanner (Java Platform SE 8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

let me know, if you have any confusion.